# when i upload a file it showing error like c:\inetpub\vhosts

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have develop a small web application in asp.net (c#) for uploading files into data base it is working fine in my local machine .But when i tested in the server it showing error like

```
 C:\inetpub\vhosts\crosstouch.com\httpdocs\Images\100898.jpeg' is denied
```

what can i do to resolve this problem please help me....

Comment: Are you saving the uploaded files on disk first?

Comment: yes, he want to upload files on disk.

Comment: Hi thank you giving response, i have save the uploded files in serverpath images folder.

Comment: If you want to put the files in a DB don't save them to disk first.

Comment: just i upload the image name only into data base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the you wont have write access to this directory. See this note for IIS6 or search MSDN for whatever version you're using.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816117

Comment: Thank you for giving valuable link

Answer (score 1):

Give write permission to IISUSER in
C:\inetpub\vhosts\crosstouch.com\httpdocs\Images folder

Answer (score 0):

give  a permission to Images folder..
i think you are using Plesk Panel for Handle it....
use Hosting Control Panel and Give permission...